# Why does calling the main method of a different class not work correctly?

Tags: java, swing, class

I'm in the process of writing a game. The game plays background music while it is running. This works fine, and I've decided to add a main menu, as their are three types of this game:

- Single Player
- Two Player
- Online

When I run these classes individually (which have their own main methods - obviously), they work perfectly fine. However, in my Welcome Menu class, which is responsible for the main menu (all necessary imports are there, just not shown here):

```
public class WelcomeMenu implements ActionListener {

public void setButtonBG(JButton button, String imgPath) throws IOException //this method is reponsible for setting images to their corresponding JButton(s)
{
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(imgPath));
    ImageIcon sp = new ImageIcon(img);
    button.setIcon(sp);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
}


private JFrame welcomeWindow = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
private JButton singlePlayerButton = new JButton();
private JButton twoPlayerButton = new JButton();
private JButton onlineButton = new JButton();
public WelcomeMenu() throws IOException
{
    //START OF CONSTRUCTOR
    //Main window is being sized, default way to close, and internal layout
    welcomeWindow.setSize(600, 420);
    welcomeWindow.setLayout(new CardLayout());
    //Object res = this.getClass().getResource("/");
    //System.out.println(res);
    BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/mainMenuBG.jpg"));
    welcomeWindow.setContentPane(new backImage(bf)); // adding created component to the JFrame using the backImage class
    welcomeWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    welcomeWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    welcomeWindow.setResizable(false);
    welcomeWindow.setVisible(true);

    //setting the icon
    try
    {
        java.net.URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/icon.png");
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image img = kit.createImage(url);
        welcomeWindow.setIconImage(img);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException n)
    {
        System.out.println("Image could not be fetched.");
    }

    //adding custom buttons

    //ImageIcon singlePlayer = new ImageIcon("images/singlePlayerButton.jpg");

    //setting sizes
    singlePlayerButton.setSize(387, 72);
    twoPlayerButton.setSize(387, 72);
    onlineButton.setSize(387, 72);

    //setting background images to buttons
    setButtonBG(singlePlayerButton, "images/sPlayerButton.jpg");
    setButtonBG(twoPlayerButton, "images/tPlayerButton.jpg");
    setButtonBG(onlineButton, "images/mPlayerButton.jpg");

    //adding listeners
    singlePlayerButton.addActionListener(this);
    twoPlayerButton.addActionListener(this);
    onlineButton.addActionListener(this);

    //adding the custom buttons
    welcomeWindow.add(singlePlayerButton);
    welcomeWindow.add(twoPlayerButton);
    welcomeWindow.add(onlineButton);

    //setting locations and visibility
    singlePlayerButton.setLocation(110, 90);
    singlePlayerButton.setVisible(true);

    twoPlayerButton.setLocation(110, 182);
    twoPlayerButton.setVisible(true);

    onlineButton.setLocation(110, 274);
    onlineButton.setVisible(true);

    //END OF CONSTRUCTOR
}
public static TicTacToeTP spg;
//All actions are done here
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource() == singlePlayerButton)
    {
        System.out.println("<LOG> SINGLE PLAYER GAME REQUESTED");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(welcomeWindow, "This game mode has not been implemented yet.");
    }
    if(e.getSource() == twoPlayerButton)
    {
        System.out.println("<LOG> TWO PLAYER GAME REQUESTED");

        try
        {
            //spg = new TicTacToeTP("images/black-squareMod_RED.jpg");
            //spg.playBackgroundSong();
            TicTacToeTP.main(null);

        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            System.out.println("IO EXCEPTION!");
        }

        welcomeWindow.setVisible(false);
        welcomeWindow.dispose(); 
    }
    if(e.getSource() == onlineButton)
    {
        System.out.println("<LOG> ONLINE GAME REQUESTED");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(welcomeWindow, "This game mode has not been implemented yet.");
    }



}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
            {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
               try
               {
                   UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
               }
               catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
               {

               }
            }
            });
    new WelcomeMenu();

}


}
```

... if I click the Two Player button, for example, it plays the audio ONLY. None of my other components load. Just an empty JFrame. Notice how in the actionPerformed() method, I tried both TicTacToeTP.main(null) and (commented out, now) instantiating a new TicTacToeTP object AND calling the playBackgroundSong() method. If I eliminate this methods call, and just instantiate the object, it works fine - but no music.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Here is the playBackgroundSong() method:

```
private Player p = null;
    //private InputStream fis = null;
    public void playBackgroundSong() //responsible for playing background music
    {
       //PausablePlayer p = null;
       InputStream fis = null;
       ArrayList<InputStream> stream = new ArrayList<InputStream>(); //this ArrayList contains multiple audio files that the method will loop through >> defined below

       stream.add(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/01 Intro.mp3"));
       stream.add(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/Basic space - The XX - Instrumental.mp3"));
       stream.add(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/Mirrors [ Upbeat Electronic Instrumental ] Spence Mills HQ Free Beat Download 2012.mp3"));
       stream.add(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/Static [ Aggressive Dark Pop Hip Hop Rap Instrumental ] Spence Mills Free Beat Download Link 2012 HD.mp3"));
       stream.add(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/System Shock 2 soundtrack Med Sci 1.mp3"));
       stream.add(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/System Shock 2 Soundtrack Ops 2.mp3"));
       stream.add(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/01 Intro.mp3"));

       Collections.shuffle(stream);

       for(int i = 0; i < stream.size(); i++)
       {
            try 
            {
                fis = stream.get(i);
            } 
            catch (NullPointerException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(TicTacToeTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try 
            {
                p = new Player(fis);
            } 
            catch (JavaLayerException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(TicTacToeTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try 
            {
                p.play();
            } 
            catch (JavaLayerException ee) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(TicTacToeTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ee);
            } 


       }
       playBackgroundSong();
    }
```

Comment: Did I understand this correctly? You are trying to call the main method of another class?

Comment: Yes, but it is not running correctly.

Comment: Okay...why are you calling the main method and not instantiating the class normally? main methods are not supposed to be called. They're more like "start" buttons. If you need functionality of a class, you just make objects. I understand you've tried instantiating and you get no music. There's a flaw in your program. Don't call some other class's main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be playing a long-running bit of code, `playBackgroundSong()`, on the Swing event dispatch thread or EDT. This thread is responsible for painting the GUI and interacting and responding to user input, and if it gets tied up, the program essentially freezes. This might not have been an issue when you called this method in the main method -- basically off of the Swing event thread, but is an issue when it is specifically called on the event dispatch thread. A possible solution: play your music in a background thread. A SwingWorker might work well for you, and there are decent tutorials on the use of these and the EDT. Google "[Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)", and check out what will likely be the first hit for more.

As an aside: you usually don't want to call another class's main method. Instead create an instance of the other class and use it.

---

**Edit** You state:

> Thanks. Looking at this part: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html Seems to explain what I want to do, correct? I am reading it all, by the way

Actually you could go even simpler. Since you're not waiting for a result from your `playBackgroundSong()`, you could possibly just call it in its own simple thread by just wrapping it in a Runnable and then putting that in a Thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    playBackgroundSong();
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: That makes sense, but can you explain how I can go about playing the audio in a separate thread? Do I just put the method in a different class? I don't quite understand what threads are.

Comment: Again, please have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) as it will explain a lot of the details since you will need to do a bit of reading to fully understand this.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at this part: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html

Seems to explain what I want to do, correct? I am reading it all, by the way.

Comment: Thanks a million. That worked perfectly. I really appreciate your insight. Plus, I understand threads a lot better now :)